# How do I make Power bi show all data as is and not as error?

Tags: powerbi

I have a set of data ~36 000 rows from which in one column there are numbers and numbers with text (100567563; WT1632366; 3275-2422 etc.) I need it to show the data as it is. It's not an error and I have tried changing what the data is (text numbers general in excel and in Power bi with no success. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

In power bi ensure that you have the datatype of that column as text, It works absolutely fine for me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Power Query previews the dataset, and determines the datatype from the first 1000 rows. From your question I'm going to assume that the first lot of previewed rows are numerical.

You can order your Excel file to have the first rows as 'WT1632366' then when it loads the data it will convert it to the text/string type, and load the numerical columns as text.

If you look in the query editor, you will see a 'changed type', you can see the column name and the format. In the below image I have a column called 'Data' you can change it from:

```
"Data", Int64.Type
```

to

```
"Data", type text
```

And it should load. 
Note: If you insert a step after it that does this, it may still not load and error

[image]

In the image, the first 1200 rows are the number 1, the 1201 row is the text 'ABC' this will fail on load unless you change formating to text. You can do this by clicking on the column and clicking on the '123' and change it from the selection to text. If it asked to replace current step use that option.

Once the datatypes are set it will not reavelate them on later loads, so you don't have to worry about data type changes

[image]